# How to hibernate Debian with Secure Boot enabled and fully encrypted disk?

Tags: debian, kde, hibernate, secure-boot

I'd like to be able to hibernate another one of my Debian/KDE machines because it's practical and I'd like to save some energy.
[I can't hibernate another one which has a swapfile and Secure Boot currently disabled.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526907/how-to-hibernate-debian-with-swapfile-on-home-partition-of-fully-encrypted-disk)

The machine runs Debian10/KDE, has Secure Boot enabled and currently doesn't have a swapfile but a swap-partition (which is larger than the RAM). The hard disk is fully encrypted. I already tried the following:

- In the DE I went to Leave but unlike on my other machine there is no entry for "Hibernate". When I search for "Hibernate" the button appears but I can't right click it for more info and nothing happens when I click it.
- Installing uswsusp and then running `sudo s2disk`. This returns:

```
s2disk: Could not open the snapshot device. Reason: Operation not permitted
```

- Installing hibernate and running `sudo hibernate`. This returns:

```
hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.  
UdevQt: unhandlet device action "unbind"  
UdevQt: unhandled device action "unbind"  
UdevQt: unhandlet device action "bind"  
UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
```

- Installing pm-utils and the executing `sudo pm-hibernate`. This returns nothing and nothing happens.
- Running `sudo systemctl hibernate`.

```
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb "hibernate" not supported
```

Searching syslog for "error" or "hibern" doesn't show anything.

Is it because of security issues? I intend to change the swap-partition to a swapfile later. Hibernating with Secure Boot should be fine when the disk is fully encrypted.

Comment: For some reason I only got this to work with openSUSE installer and its handling/configuration of GRUB2. I assume that you are using LVM on LUKS with `/`, `/home` and `swap` all inside the LVM container?

Comment: Please post your kernel commandline (`cat /proc/cmdline`, it needs `resume`) and `lsblk` output.

Comment: `sudo lvdisplay` shows that all 3 partitions are inside the volume group. cmdline has: `BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.19.0.5-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/Debian-root ro quiet apparmor=1 security=apparmor`. `lsblk` also shows all 3 partitions being part of the same crypt container. What do you mean with it needing resume? Do I need to edit uswsusp.conf and grub as described here?: https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition

Comment: Let's stay with a swap partition for the moment and get it to work because I believe doing that in a file is more complicated. I see your problem and will start with an answer when I can access the laptop where it works.

Comment: well, for me on Debian testing, it works for suspend to RAM, with disk fully encrypted LUKS on LVM. I also enabled secure boot with custom keys. In both case(secure boot enabled/disabled) it doesn't work for me. I have no DE.